# Perl XML parser to extract the default values of the optional attributes fromt the xsd file

Tags: perl

I need to parse an XML file through a perl script. While parsing the file, I need to validate it with the corresponding xsd(schema definition) file. The xsd file contains some optional attribute with a default value being provided. I have to parse the xml file in such a way so that I should be able to fetch the default value for all the attribute that are not present in the XML(from xsd). The issue is that I couldn't find any appropriate parser in perl for this Job.I could find a parser that is able to validate the file but couldn't get the default value of attributes that are not present the XML.
Can you please suggest me any parser/module that can help me in getting the required data.

Note: I need the values of the attributes that are not present in the XML to make a complete record for database insertion.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [XML::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile/). It *appears* to me that the default values feature is supported, but I've never actually used the module at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the database schema so all fields have defaults.